# Dados de um objeto ficam nulos após ler de um CSV

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

Eu tenho a seguinte classe Java:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String employee_name;

    private String user_id;
    private String domain;
    private String email;
    private String role;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Pessoa [employee_name=" + employee_name + ", user_id=" + user_id + ", domain=" + domain + ", email="
                + email + ", role=" + role + "]";
    }

    // Gets e Sets omitidos para ficar menor

}
```

O seguinte arquivo CSV:

```
employee_name,user_id,domain,email,role
BurtonMStephenson,BMS0001,dtaa.com,Burton.M.Stephenson@dtaa.com,Security
Keelie M Goodwin,KMG0002,dtaa.com,Keelie.M.Goodwin@dtaa.com,Engineer
Dara O Craig,DOC0003,dtaa.com,Dara.O.Craig@dtaa.com,VP
```

Tenho a classe responsável por ler o arquivo CSV e jogar em objetos do tipo `Pessoa`:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import com.opencsv.CSVReaderBuilder;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBean;
import com.opencsv.bean.CsvToBeanBuilder;



public class LerLinhasOpenCsv {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get("LDAP_head.csv"));

                CsvToBean<Pessoa> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
                    .withType(Pessoa.class).build();

            List<Pessoa> pessoas = csvToBean.parse();

            for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas)
                System.out.println(pessoa.toString());


    }   
}
```

Mas quando realizo a impressão aparece tudo `null`:

```
Pessoa [employee_name=null, user_id=null, domain=null, email=null, role=null]
Pessoa [employee_name=null, user_id=null, domain=null, email=null, role=null]
Pessoa [employee_name=null, user_id=null, domain=null, email=null, role=null]
Pessoa [employee_name=null, user_id=null, domain=null, email=null, role=null]
Pessoa [employee_name=null, user_id=null, domain=null, email=null, role=null]
```

Comment: Fiz um teste aqui com o opencsv 4.0 e os dados só ficam nulos se a classe `Pessoa` não tiver os *setters*. Eu coloquei os *setters* nela e funcionou, os dados ficam preenchidos e nenhum fica nulo. Por favor verifique se é isso ou se falta mais algum detalhe que vc não mencionou - e se for o caso, basta clicar em **[edit]** e adicionar estas informações na pergunta

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, era isto mesmo, acabei não implementando os setters. Obrigado.

Comment: @hkotsubo formalize sua resposta e joelson marque-a com resolvida quando o autor da resposta escrevê-la.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve adicionar os *setters* na classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa {
    ....

    public void setEmployee_name(String employee_name) {
        this.employee_name = employee_name;
    }

    public void setUser_id(String user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }

    ... etc
}
```

Sem isso o opencsv não consegue setar os valores, e por isso todos ficam `null`. Adicionando os *setters*, os valores são preenchidos corretamente:

```
Pessoa [employee_name=BurtonMStephenson, user_id=BMS0001, domain=dtaa.com, email=Burton.M.Stephenson@dtaa.com, role=Security]
Pessoa [employee_name=Keelie M Goodwin, user_id=KMG0002, domain=dtaa.com, email=Keelie.M.Goodwin@dtaa.com, role=Engineer]
Pessoa [employee_name=Dara O Craig, user_id=DOC0003, domain=dtaa.com, email=Dara.O.Craig@dtaa.com, role=VP]
```

---

Outro detalhe é usar as convenções de código do Java e evitar `_` nos nomes dos campos, e em vez disso usar *camelCase*: `employeeName` em vez de `employee_name` e `userId` em vez de `user_id`.

Entendo que você tenha feito isso para que os nomes dos campos no arquivo CSV correspondam aos nomes dos campos da classe. Mas você pode usar nomes diferentes e mapeá-los com a anotação `@CsvBindByName`.

O detalhe é que, ao colocar esta anotação em um campo, eu tive que colocá-la em todos. Quando o campo tem um nome diferente no arquivo CSV, eu coloco isso na anotação. Quando o nome é o mesmo, basta colocar a anotação sem parâmetros.

```
public class Pessoa {

    // employeeName corresponde à coluna employee_name do arquivo
    @CsvBindByName(column = "employee_name")
    private String employeeName;

    // userId corresponde à coluna user_id do arquivo
    @CsvBindByName(column = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    // campos domain, email e role tem o mesmo nome no CSV (usar anotação sem parâmetros)

    @CsvBindByName
    private String domain;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String email;

    @CsvBindByName
    private String role;

    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    .... // demais setters para os outros campos
}
```